# Unable to on Template Path Hints in magento

Tags: magento

I have on the hints from back end developer template hints for both default configuration and main website.But hints have not shown on front end. Tell me how i on that hints.

Comment: How did you enabled template path hints in the "default configuration"? I'm curious, because from what I know it is available only on website and store view scopes.

Answer (score 4):

You need to select the store view which you are using it from admin->system->configuration : 
you will find the Current Configuration Scope: on the left top 
Need to select the store view which you are using it.

if you are using default store view select it & than go to developer->debug->template path hint select Yes here

click on save config

clear the cache

check on frond end

Hope it is useful for you

Answer (score 2):

Magento 1.8.1

Follow this path :

Magento Top menu System->configuration->Left menu Advanced->Developer

(Click on Developer link) -> Debug (Second position from top)
there are two option in list by default

Go to -> Current Configuration Scope option [top left drop down] -> select your store view where you are working.

Like Main website->Main store-> English or Main website->Main store-> Franch

with select drop down option English or Franch or German (or where you are working) 
You will see a one more option in **debug section** with name **Template Path Hints**  make this **yes**.

Answer (score 0):

To enable magneto template hits in Magento ver. 2.4.4

Follow the steps below:

1. Just click to "STORE" in left menu in admin area.
2. then select "Configuration" form sub menu.
3. Now you are Configuration setting page. scroll down and click on "Developer" under "Advance" menu.
4. Now you will see setting for template hints there.  Choose "Yes" for "Enable Template Path Hints for Storefront"  and if you want only enable if URL param found then also chose "Yes" in "Enable Hints for Storefront with URL Parameter"
5. You can also customise URL parameter by uncheck "Use system value" and use desired value for "Parameter Value"

For more reference please check the image attached.

[Attachment - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmRHz.png),
[Attachment - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QSet.png)